# Protecting the creation of associated objects in Rails 3 with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations

I've got Devise set up in my Rails 3 app.  Devise is configured to work with a model called Publisher.  Publisher has several associated models.  I'm having a hard time conceptualising how to protect creating/destroying/viewing these associated objects with Devise.  I'm used to creating an associated record with something like:

```
pub = Publisher.find(:params[publisher_id])
pub.books << Book.create!(:title => "War and Peace")
```

I'm sure I'm just missing something straightforward, but where do I implement logic that confirms that whoever is logged in as `pub` is actually the person creating this association?  Is it as straightforward as something like this?:

`pub = Publisher.find(current_publisher)`

If that's the case, where do I implement this?  In our implementation, these records will be created via a `POST` to `/publishers/:publisher_id/books(.:format)`.  Does this mean that the should occur in the `#create` method in BooksController?  I know this is all elementary, but I'm only exposed to RoR once every six months or so--never long enough get a lasting, solid grasp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create new `Book` instances using the `Publisher`'s `books` association, like this:

```
current_publisher.books.build(:title => "War and Peace")
```

This adds a new book to the association and assigns the publisher to it for you.

Comment: Makes sense.  Where would be the most idiomatic place for this logic to reside?  I'm guessing it would be in a custom `PublishersController`?

Comment: No, you are creating books, so the `BooksController`'s `create` action would be the place to do this.